# how remove field from admin view during add form django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have the following model

```
class Organizer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

I have a field created_by of all the users. I don't want to show on the front end in admin form during adding form. how to do that. and save the current login user id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for hiding `created_by`

```
class OrganizerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    // show fileds on form
    fields = ('name', 'phone', 'created_at')

admin.site.register(Organizer, OrganizerAdmin)
```

and for save login user

```
def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
        user = request.user
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not change or not instance.created_by:
            instance.created_by = user
        instance.modified_by = user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an admin form in admin.py and register that form to the model:

admin.py:

```
class OrganizerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'phone', 'created_at')

admin.site.register(Organizer, OrganizerAdmin)
```

you can read more about fields in admin page [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields)

Comment: thanks for answer but my questing is not in listing.. in add form i want to remove that field.. i do update my question

Comment: oh you only want on add page ,i had edited my answer for it

Comment: glad to help, you can accept it as an answer if it work for you